# Destroy button rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a destroy for menu_items but do not know what and where to put in the information. I think it should be in the menus controller but not sure please help. this is the form i would like to put the button in after the hidden field:

```
=form_for ["admin", @menu] do |f|
  %p
    =f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"

  %h3 Menu Items
  =f.fields_for :menu_items do |c|
    %p
      =c.text_field :title,placeholder: "Title", class: "form-control"
      =c.text_field :url, placeholder: "enter URL or path here",class: "form-control"
      =c.hidden_field :id






  %p
    =f.submit

  %p
    =link_to "back", admin_menus_path, class: "btn btn-danger"
```

**MenusController:**

```
module Admin
  class MenusController < AdminController
    def index
      @menus = Menu.all
    end

    def new
      @menu = Menu.new
      10.times {@menu.menu_items.build}
    end

    def create
      @menu = Menu.new menu_params
      if @menu.save
        redirect_to admin_menus_path, notice: "Menu created."
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    def update
      @menu = Menu.find params[:id]
      if @menu.update_attributes menu_params
        redirect_to admin_menus_path, notice: "Menu updated."
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end

    def edit
      @menu = Menu.find params[:id]
      10.times {@menu.menu_items.build}
    end

    def destroy
      @menu = Menu.find params[:id]
      if @menu.destroy
        redirect_to admin_menus_path, notice: "Menu deleted!"
      else
        redirect_to admin_menus_path, alert: "Menu was NOT deleted!!!!"   
      end
    end

    protected
    def menu_params
      params.require(:menu).permit(:name, :menu_items_attributes => [:title, :url, :id])
    end
  end
end
```

please help!! :(

to get rid of this mess:
[menu page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHULB.png)

[Menu Items Page linking from Menu Page (edit button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I78sD.png)

P.S
If you dont happen to know the answer and know the technical wording of the question i am asking i would greatly appreciate if you could word this question differently. as i dont actually know what to call the ":menu_items" compared to @menu Thank you.

Comment: You want to put the destroy button in a form? Thats akward.

Comment: only because after the menu item has been created it cant be deleted from the main menu page and shows a numbered point. dont like the mess its causing on that page: "4. " after all it is a cms and the user need not have to face that confusion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I understood you have `menu has_many menu_items` and `menu_items belongs_to menu`, and when you wanna edit your `menu` you have ability remove already existing `menu_items`?

I would do it in next way:

1. controller

   def menu_params

   params.require(:menu).permit(:name, :menu_items_attributes => [:title, :url, :id, :_destroy])

   end
2. Add button `DESTROY` to each `menu_item` and with JavaScript, by clicking just add hidden attribute `:_destroy`
3. now when you click `SUBMIT` your `menu` controller will get `:_destroy` attribute and will destroy your obejct.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you Oleg i will try that. But just to be sure we are on the right page, will the destroy button destroy all of my menu_items or only the items i press destroy under as i actually want destroy buttons under each of the menu  items (image added for menu items page above). again thank you so much for your patience as this is my first ever project.

Comment: you should add `:_destroy` attribute to that `menu_item` what you wanna remove, and when rails in controller get it this `menu_item` will be destroyed. For example object `menu` has 2 `menu_item` - ids: [10, 11], on view you click `destroy` button on id 11. JS add to appropriate object attr `:_destroy  true` and push `SABMIT`.Controller get params `params[:menu] = {name: 'My Name', menu_items_attributes: { title: 'Menu Item id 11', id: 11, url: 'google.com', _destroy: true }}`, now if you use this attributes `menu_item` with `id` 11 will be removed.